# What am I doing wrong and how to debug memory leaks with python's asyncio?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-asyncio

I've got code like this:

```
async def worker(self):
    while True:
        proxies = get_proxies()
        for proxy in proxies:
            await self.add_proxy_to_queue(proxy)

async def add_proxy_to_queue(self, proxy):
    while self.proxies_semaphore.locked():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)

    asyncio.ensure_future(self.process_proxy(proxy))

async def process_proxy(self, proxy):
    async with self.proxies_semaphore:
        # send network request and wait for the resposne with timeout
```

I've changed it like this:

```
async def worker(self):
    while True:
        proxies = get_proxies()
        for proxy in proxies:
            await self.add_proxy_to_queue(proxy)

async def add_proxy_to_queue(self, proxy):
    async with self.proxies_semaphore:  # <-- HERE ARE THE CHANGES
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.process_proxy(proxy))

async def process_proxy(self, proxy):
    async with self.proxies_semaphore:
        # send network request and wait for the resposne with timeout
```

and it's still leaking, but much slower.

What am I doing wrong and how to debug asyncio code, how say to look inside event loop and see which tasks are actually there?

Comment: One thing I've just found is https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.all_tasks it allows to show all running tasks inside loop, but works only for python 3.7

Comment: Also, checkout Debugging with Asyncio, https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html

Comment: @devalone it's not the fact that you're leaking: it's up to garbage collector to decide when and how to cleanup. Anyway, try to call GC manually like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46924539/1113207), it may help.

Comment: Hm, it seems that second one is working and the problem was in sleeping inside loop